# Why this broken program always runs?

Tags: java, multithreading, static, thread-safety

I was trying examples from JCIP and Below program should not work but even if I execute it say 20 times it always work which means `ready` and `number` are becoming visible even if it should in this case

```
public class NoVisibility {
private static boolean ready;
private static int number;

private static class ReaderThread implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        while (!ready)
            Thread.yield();
        System.out.println(number);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
    //Number of Processor is 4 so 4+1 threads
    new Thread(new ReaderThread()).start();
    new Thread(new ReaderThread()).start();
    new Thread(new ReaderThread()).start();
    new Thread(new ReaderThread()).start();
    new Thread(new ReaderThread()).start();

    number = 42;
    ready = true;
}
}
```

On my machine it always prints

```
4 -- Number of Processors
42
42
42
42
42
```

`According to Listing 3.1 of JCIP It should sometimes print 0 or should never terminate it also suggest that there is no gaurantee that ready and number written by main thread will be visible to reader thread`

**Update**
I added 1000ms sleep in main thread after strating all threads still same output.**I know program is broken And I expect it behave that way**

Comment: Why do you think it should not work?

Comment: `private` variables are visible to inner classes.  There's no reason this shouldn't work.

Comment: JCIP book Listing 3.1 suggests that it should print 0 or run forever.

Comment: Well, you're using multithreading in unsafe manner. It may work, it may not. It may work for you and not for me, etc.

Comment: Give us URL where did you read that?

Comment: This behavior is easy to emulate in C#, but I have neven been able to pull it off in Java.

Answer (score 3):

This program is broken since `ready` and `number` should be declared as `volatile`.
Due to the fact that `ready` and `number` are primitive variables, operations on them are atomic **but** it is **not** guaranteed that they will be visible by other threads.
It seems that the scheduler runs the threads *after* `main` and that is why they see the `number` and `ready` being initialized. But that is just one scheduling.
If you add e.g. a `sleep` in `main` so as to affect the scheduler you will see different results.
So the book is correct, there is no guarantee whether the `Runnable`s running in separate threads will ever see the variable's being updated since the variables are not declared as `volatile`.

**Update:**
The problem here is that the due to the lack of `volatile` the compiler is free to read the field `ready` just once, and reuse the cached value in each execution of the loop.
The program is inherently flawed. And with threading issues the problem usually appears when you deploy your application to the field....
From [JSL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.3):

> For example, in the following (broken) code fragment, assume that
>   this.done is a   non-volatile boolean field:
>
> while (!this.done)
>       Thread.sleep(1000);
>
> The compiler is free to read the field this.done just once, and reuse
>   the cached value in  each execution of the loop. This would mean that
>   the loop would never terminate, even if an other thread changed the
>   value of this.done.

Comment: I added 1000ms sleep in main thread after starting all the threads still result is same as soon as sleep ends all threads terminate

Comment: _Might_ see different results, depending on how long the sleep is. The point that the JCIP is trying to make is that the above multithreaded code should not be depended upon for the other threads to receive the updated value in any thread safe way, assuming that they run _before_ the main thread is able to set `number` and `ready` fields. As Cratylus is pointing out, the set operations are atomic, but the other `Thread`s having their memory cache invalidated is not guaranteed. I would note that it _should_ be terminated rather dependably on any JVM, but it's unsafe due to above description.

Comment: Even once you have added a sleep, there is no guarantee that it will work or won't work. It will depend on many factors, including JVM options, machine architecture, compiler optimizations etc.

Answer (score 1):

What is important to keep in mind is that a broken concurrent program might always work with the right combination of JVM's options, machine architecture etc. That does not make it a good program, as it will probably fail in a different context: the fact that no concurrency issue shows up does not mean there aren't any.

In other words, you can't prove that a concurrent program is correct with testing.

Back to your specific example, I see the same behaviour as what you describe. But, if I remove the `Thread.yield()` instruction in the while loop, 3 out of 8 threads stop and print 42, but the rest don't and the program never ends.