# Trouble understanding the semantics of volatile in Java

Tags: java, volatile

I've been reading up about the use of `volatile` variables in Java. I understand that they ensure instant visibility of their latest updates to all the threads running in the system on different cores/processors. However no atomicity of the operations that caused these updates is ensured. I see the following literature being used frequently

> A write to a volatile field happens-before every read of that same field .

This is where I am a little confused. Here's a snippet of code which should help me better explain my query.

```
volatile int x = 0;
volatile int y = 0; 

Thread-0:                       |               Thread-1:
                                |
if (x==1) {                     |               if (y==1) {
     return false;              |                    return false; 
} else {                        |               } else {
     y=1;                       |                   x=1;
     return true;               |                   return true;
}                               |               }
```

Since x & y are both `volatile`, we have the following happens-before edges

1. between the write of y in Thread-0 and read of y in Thread-1
2. between the write of x in Thread-1 and read of x in Thread-0

Does this imply that, at any point of time, only one of the threads can be in its 'else' block(since a write would happen before the read)?

It may well be possible that Thread-0 starts, loads x, finds it value as 0 and right before it is about to write y in the else-block, there's a context switch to Thread-1 which loads y finds it value as 0 and thus enters the else-block too. Does `volatile` guard against such context switches (seems very unlikely)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I think this question is a bit in the weeds, the gist is that `volatile` indicates that the value of the variable may change outside the scope of the current thread, and that its value must always be read before use.

In principle, the statement you're quoting is really saying that prior to replacing the value with the current thread, the value will be read.

Your example is a race condition, both threads may return true, neither may return true, or they may each return a different value -- the semantics of `volatile` won't define execution for your example (I'd encourage you to compile and run it and see that the output varies).

A common way to illustrate the behavior of `volatile` is to run two threads, where one thread updates shared state and to see what happens when the field is marked, and when it isn't:

```
class VolatileTest implements Runnable
{
        // try with and without volatile
        private volatile boolean stopRunning = false;

        public void triggerStop(){
             stopRunning = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void run(){
             while(!stopRunning);
             System.out.println("Finished.");
        }

        public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
        {
            final VolatileTest test = new VolatileTest();
            new Thread(test).start();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            test.triggerStop() = false;
        }
}
```

In this example, failure to mark `stopRunning` as `volatile` can lead to the `while` loop continuing forever, as unless `stopRunning` is marked as `volatile` it's not required to read the value on each iteration.

Comment: I tried running this code. So I used the above piece of code as a trylock sort-of function between two threads and busy-waited on this function from the calling threads. Strangely I'm able to achieve mutual exclusion between the two threads everytime. Here's the code -http://db.tt/JFAzNDkS

Comment: If you add a third thread that waits a random amount of time the results should change. I'll edit my answer to include a slightly more common test of volatile functionality.

Comment: This code runs without volatile also. Please check question asked by me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12341174/why-this-broken-program-always-runs

Comment: @AmitD: it might well do, but it's not guaranteed to.

Answer (score 2):

**Semantics of Volatile**

The problem you are referring to is a variation of [Dekker’s Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dekker%27s_algorithm). With plenty of details on [google](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=Dekkers%20Algorithm%20Details) on different implementations and details regarding it.

> If two processes attempt to enter a critical section at the same time, the algorithm will allow only one process in, based on whose turn it is. If one process is already in the critical section, the other process will busy wait for the first process to exit. This is done by the use of two flags, flag[0] and flag[1], which indicate an intention to enter the critical section and a turn variable which indicates who has priority between the two processes.

*Wikipedia covers the relevance of `volatile` with Dekker's Alogrithm*

**Volatile Information**

But I found this [article](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaConcurrency/article.html#memorymodel_atomic) explains `volatile` perfectly in a single sentence.

> If a variable is declared as volatile then is guaranteed that any thread which reads the field will see the most recently written value. ([Lars Vogel](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaConcurrency/article.html#memorymodel_atomic), 2008)
>
> Essentially, volatile is used to indicate that a variable's value will be modified by different threads. ([javamex](https://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile.shtml), 2012)

**Massey University : Concurrency Volatile Lecture Slide**

[image: Massey Lecture Slide]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/zbntvu15.jcz.png))</sub>

Source: [Professor Hans W. Guesgen](http://www-ist.massey.ac.nz/hwguesgen/)

If you don't yet understand `volatile` look into how `atomicity` works.

Answer (score 1):

> Does this imply that, at any point of time, only one of the threads can be in its 'else' block(since a write would happen before the read)?

No it does not.

> Does volatile guard against such context switches (seems very unlikely)?

No it does not guard against that.  The race condition that you identified is really there.

This points to the fact that volatiles are not a general purpose synchronization mechanism.  Rather they allow you to *avoid synchronizing* in certain situations which revolve around a single variable that can be read or written in a single memory operation.

In your example, there are two variables ...

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a bad example here.  Both threads can get into the else block quite easily (thread 0 reads x & checks against 1, then thread 1 reads y and checks against 1).

The example of interest is something like this:

```
thread 0          thread 1

x = 1             y = 1
if (y == 0) {     if (x == 0) {
}                 }
```

Both threads cannot get into the `if` block if `x` and `y` are volatile.

Answer (score 0):

From the Java Language Specification, a volatile field has the following properties:

> A field may be declared volatile, in which case a thread must reconcile its
>   working copy of the field with the master copy every time it accesses the variable.
>   Moreover, operations on the master copies of one or more volatile variables on
>   behalf of a thread are performed by the main memory in exactly the order that the
>   thread requested.

From the above,

> Does this imply that, at any point of time, only one of the threads can be in its 'else' block(since a write would happen before the read)?

This will not happen as volatile ensures that a thread is reading the latest value of the variable in memory and not from the local copy it has. There is no possibility of blocking by declaring a variable as volatile. You should use the `synchronized` concept to serialize writes to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

all volatile reads and writes on all variables are in a total order (the synchronization order).

A write to a volatile variable v happens-before all **subsequent** reads of v by any thread (where "subsequent" is defined according to the synchronization order)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4

Answer (score 0):

> **Volatile guarantees visibility, synchronization guarantees both visibility and atomicity**

Only guarantee it provides is if `x` or `y` updated by one thread then update will be visible to all the threads.
The order of execution solely depends on how your threads are running. The answer to context switch question is no since comparison happens before entering so it will be only one time and it will be based on value of variable at that time. This might possible if you have multiple comparisons for the same variable.

The best way to use volatile is for maintaining state variables of the class. Where in any new assignment will reflect in all threads which are accessing that class

If you look at the source code of  `ThreadPoolExecutor` several state variables are volatile.

One of them happens to be `runState` which determines state of the `ThreadPoolExecutor`. Now when `shutdown()` is called `runState` is updated to `SHUTDOWN`  so that methods which accepts the task which are `execute` `submit` stops accepting the task which happens to be a simple `if(runState==RUNNING)`

Below code is `execute` method of [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)

In below code if you see no additional synchronization is needed for `poolSize`, `runState` variables because they are volatile state variables.

```
public void execute(Runnable command) {
    if (command == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    if (**poolSize** >= corePoolSize || !addIfUnderCorePoolSize(command)) {//poolSize  volatile
        if (**runState** == RUNNING && workQueue.offer(command)) {//runstate volatile
            if (**runState** != RUNNING || **poolSize** == 0)//runstate volatile
                ensureQueuedTaskHandled(command);
        }
        else if (!addIfUnderMaximumPoolSize(command))
            reject(command); // is shutdown or saturated
    }
  }
```

**When not to use it?**

> When variable needs to be used in atomic operations or when one variable value depends on another variable value  e.g. Increment i++.

**Alternative**

> Atomic variables are called as **better volatile** which has memory semantics as volatile but provide you additional operations. e.g. incrementAndGet() operation provided by AtomicInteger.