# Java concurrency in practice Listing 3.1

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm reading Java concurrency in practice which so far is really interesting

I've encountered Listing 3.1 with the following code example:

```
public class NoVisibility {
private static boolean ready;
private static int number;
private static class ReaderThread extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        while (!ready)
            Thread.yield();
        System.out.println(number);
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ReaderThread().start();
    number = 42;
    ready = true;
}
}
```

I understand how theoretically this code snippet can go wrong.

I've decided to go and check it myself so I entered the code to my IDE
and ran it for about 40 times and every single time the output was the same: 42.

So I'm curious, how many times (statistically) I should try and run it until I see a failed example and why is the failure so rare?
I've tried searching on SO but all I found was: [question about “Java Concurrency in Practice” example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919469/question-about-java-concurrency-in-practice-example) but it's **irrelevant** to my question since I **do** understand how it can happen but just curious on why is it so hard to get a failing execution

Thanks :)

Comment: Lmao @Bohemian you may be mod, but you definitely have trouble reading.

Comment: possible duplicate of [java thread visibility](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868187/java-thread-visibility)

Comment: Boann, you're probably right. I still like wha'eve's answer more :) My bad for missing it though (I did look at other similar posts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reordering can be done at the JIT level or at the CPU level. Your code is too short for the JIT to kick in so it would have to be the CPU.

For such a simple operation there is really no reason why the CPU would start messing up with your code so you will probably never observe that reordering and your program will always print 42.

The point of that example is not to say that it *will* break, but that *in theory* it *could* break.

See also: [Why this broken program always runs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12341174/why-this-broken-program-always-runs)

Comment: If there isn't any reordering going on, shouldn't ReaderThread see the default values ready=false and number=0 then?

Comment: @Paedolos What I meant is that ready and number will be published at the same time and when the thread sees ready as true it will also see number as 42.

Comment: I tried putting the "clear values" "run thread" "set values" in a loop, and the results were very inconsistent, lots of 0's at start and then all 42's. How'd you explain that? Adding volatile did not help, which is even more weird.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, your explanation was very clear. I figured it might be too short but had to make sure :)